# How to join sharepoint list using webpart in VS 2010?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, datagridview

I created 2 lists in SharePoint:

- **customer** having the columns:

  - id
  - name
  - address
- **product** having the columns:

  - id
  - customer_id (lookup)
  - productname

I want to display  all product details belongs to each customer in [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.aspx) using web part in VS2010.

Comment: I just want to given the question in detail,bcoz the viewers doesnt understand the question which i have submitted earlier.

Comment: There no need to post a new question if you want to change something - **you can edit every question you posted** to improve it and add necessary details.

Comment: Okay..I am new user in stack overflow,thats why..
Thanks

Comment: Are you using SharePoint 2010? Can you write the [LINQ To SharePoint queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538250.aspx)?

Comment: I am using sharepoint 2010.I got the answer to display the single list in gridview.But joining is not working.

Comment: Can you post the code you tried to use and the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the new join features in the Camelot .NET Connector for SharePoint found at http://www.bendsoft.com/home/

Thsi will enable you to write queries like this

```
using (var connection = new SharePointConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new SharePointCommand(@"SELECT Customer.name AS Name
                , Customer.address AS Address
                , Customer.ID AS CustomerId
                , Product.ID AS ProductId
                , Product.customer_id AS ProductCustomerId
                , Product.productname AS ProductName
                FROM Customers
                INNER JOIN Log ON CustomerId = ProductCustomerId"
                , connection))
    {
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader["Name"].ToString().PadRight(30) + " : " + reader["Event"].ToString().PadRight(30) + " : " + reader["Created"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

http://www.bendsoft.com/documentation/camelot-net-connector/latest/sql-statement-syntax/join/